# Why Java Mongo Driver takes 6-10 seconds to do initial connection to Mongo Atlas?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java application and it has to connect to Mongo Atlas. We are doing connection to the database using standard java driver code snippet as shown below. However, the initial connection takes a lot of time sometimes reaches to 10 seconds which is unacceptable in our case because it impacts application start-up time.

Is it a well-known behavior of java mongo driver that it takes this much time or I am the only one who is facing this issue? When I checked with node.js, it just takes ~70-90milliseconds to connect to the same database.

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
       .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
       .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString("mongodb://username:password@host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017/test&retryWrites=true&w=majority"))
       .build();
   return MongoClients.create(settings);
```

I see the following logs when the connection is happening:

```
INFO: Cluster created with settings 
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster1 Host1
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster1 Host2
INFO: Adding discovered server cluster1 Host3
INFO: Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:29834}] to host1:27017
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:29834}] to host2:27017
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to the server with a description
INFO: Discovered cluster type of REPLICA_SET
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:31712}] to host3:27017
```